# How do I combine a basic jquery function into a shortcode within an existing contact form?

Tags: jquery, iphone, ios, facebook, wordpress

Here's the link to the page:

http://www.andrewdolph.net/wp/contact/

Here's the current code:

iphone 1-330-289-6072

```
[gpp_button color="black" title="themes" icon_left="phone" target="_blank" size="small"]iphone[/gpp_button]

[gpp_button color="black" url="http://www.facebook.com/andrewrankindolph" title="themes" icon_left="facebook-alt" target="_blank" size="small"]friend me[/gpp_button]
[gpp_button color="black" url="http://www.twitter.com/andrewdolph" title="themes" icon_left="twitter" target="_blank" size="small"]follow[/gpp_button]
[gpp_button color="black" url="http://www.linkedin.com/in/andrewdolph" title="themes" icon_left="linkedin" target="_blank" size="small"]view profile [/gpp_button]
[gpp_button color="black" url="http://www.flickr.com/photos/andrewdolph/" title="themes" icon_left="flickr" target="_blank" size="small"]view photostream[/gpp_button]

[bestwebsoft_contact_form lang=en]
```

I want to eliminate the current iphone link and make it look like the current social media buttons, but have that button call up the phone number in iOS.

How?

Comment: Also, the button is just a link.  Put `tel://` like you have in the link above.

Comment: No reason to be snarky. And, I still don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

You've already done what you need in all the other buttons.  You need to add a url attribute...

```
[gpp_button color="black" url="tel://13302896072" title="themes" icon_left="phone" target="_blank" size="small"]telephone[/gpp_button]
```

Comment: I see you've implemented this on your website.  You're welcome.